# Как отправить несколько писем в одном письме в Laravel?

Tags: laravel

У меня есть новостной сайт. Ежедневно публикуется около 10 записей. Пользователи могут подписаться на рассылку этих новостей на свою почту.

Мой сайт работает на Laravel, и прежде, чем отправить письмо пользователю, оно попадает в очередь. Например, если я публикую 10 новостей в день, то получается, что пользователь получит 10 писем.

Как в Laravel сделать так, чтобы все эти условные 10 писем были упакованы в одно письмо, которое будет отправлено пользователю один раз в день?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the site of the Russian-speaking SO community, please translate your question into Russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [планировщиком задач](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling).

Определите функцию, которая соберёт нужные записи и отправит их подписчикам. Затем используйте метод `daily`, чтобы она запускалась раз в день:

```php
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            // Send mail
        })->daily();
    }
}
```

Вы также можете продолжить использовать очереди. Тогда для запуска задания используйте метод `job`, вместо `call`:

```php
$schedule->job(new SendMail)->daily();
```